# FromSqlRaw() - Does the documentation contradict?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

When I follow this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-5.0 I get an error message:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Example:

```
Context.Entity.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeFunction({@MyParameter})", new SqlParameter("@MyParameter", "some value"))
```

However, when I follow this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql
, the SQL created is sound and the query is executed correctly:

Example:

```
Context.Entity.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeFunction(@MyParameter)", new SqlParameter("@MyParameter", "some value"))
```

Here the parameters are specified without curly braces - which I think is logical, since there is no string interpolation going on here.

It seems to me that parts of the documentation are wrong. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Dale for the edit - didn't know I should put that in a block too.

Comment: `ROM dbo...`? Don't you mean `FROM dbo...`? Neither of those statements will execute successfully with that typographical error.

Comment: It does look like an error in the docs, feel free to submit a change to fix it.

Comment: Thanks - wanted a double-check before doing this in case I'm just a blockhead at the moment ;-)

Comment: Filed an issue on GitHub. Thanks for the comments.